# Change title of template dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I was doing a react interview, but they asked me AngularJS questions. Can you please advise if I have done this correctly. In this code I am trying to change the title of template dynamically.

```
<html data-ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <title><!-- should change when ng-view changes --></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

My code is, it's not quite working:

```
app.service('template', function($scope) {
  return {
    setTitle: function(title) {
      document.title = title;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You had to write `<title>{{ myTitle }}</title>`, create a controller with app.controller('MyController', function($scope) { $scope.myTitle = title;  }); and tell angularjs to use the controller on the <html> tag via `<html ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">...</html>`. You can avoid using a controller, but then you will have to write custom directives / components which takes a bit more time to write.

Comment: Thank you @PierreEmmanuelLallemant if you post that I would love to accept that soution.